# React Timeseries Charts-normalizing by weeks

Tags: reactjs, time-series, timeserieschart

I'm trying to build charts showing crop development over a year, between several seasons.

I know that the TimeRange is set like this:

`<ChartContainer timeRange={series1.timerange()} />`

I have different timeseries, of course, from the different seasons.

I'd like to stack the charts one on top of the other, and normalize them to weeks, so that the x-axis goes from 0-52 weeks, but you can still see the date of a particular event or measurement when hovering over it.

I'd renormalize the initial data to weeks, but am afraid that would not meet the second requirement.

My data looks something like this:

```
{
            brix:   [
                        [timestamp(unixtime), value(reading)],
                        [timestamp, value],
                        [timestamp,value],
                        ...
                    ],
            pH: [
                        [timestamp(unixtime), value(reading)],
                        [timestamp, value],
                        [timestamp,value],
                        ...
                    ],
            tA: [
                        [timestamp(unixtime), value(reading)],
                        [timestamp, value],
                        [timestamp,value],
                        ...
                ]
            phenologyEvents:[
                                {
                                    startTime: "2015-03-08T09:00:00Z",
                                    endTime: "2015-03-22T14:00:00Z",
                                    percentage : 10,
                                    title: "Bud burst",
                                    type: "validated"
                                },
                                {
                                    startTime: "2015-03-08T09:00:00Z",
                                    endTime: "2015-03-22T14:00:00Z",
                                    percentage : 20,
                                    title: "Veraison",
                                    type: "predicted"
                                }
                            ]
        }
```

How should I build the TimeRange?

Comment: Can you please share your data or more of your code?

Comment: Added the data scheme.